# Copy some text and not cut it

Tags: javascript

I have a page which show some text in a paragraph. When clicked it is copied.
I want to have the text still show afterwards and not to disappear and be able to select whatever part of the text. So copy "in the background" and still have it show as a normal text that can be selected and copied.
Why? Because the copy all is a nice thing but sometimes only a selected part is needed.

This is what I have now.

```
document.querySelector('p').addEventListener('click', async event => {
  if (!navigator.clipboard) {
    // Clipboard API not available
    return
  }
  const text = event.target.innerText
  try {
    await navigator.clipboard.writeText(text)
    event.target.textContent = 'Copied to clipboard'
  } catch (err) {
    console.error('Failed to copy!', err)
  }
})
```

Answer (score 0):

You can get the selected text like outlined [here](https://www.geeksforgeeks.org/how-to-get-the-highlighted-selected-text-in-javascript/) (e.g. by using `window.getSelection();`). Then just write it to the clipboard. Just do this on a mouseup event from the element you want to select from I think